# Как на Virtualbox отменить откат к старому snapshot

Tags: virtualbox, эмулятор, виртуализация, микросервисы

Есть виртуальная машина на Virtualbox, на которой я работал продолжительное время. В самом начале работы, года 2 назад, я сделал snapshot. Сегодня, при выключении виртуалки я случайно откатился к этому самому snapshot 2х летней давности. Снэпшота текущего состояния у меня не было.  Есть ли какая-то возможность отменить откат? Пропали ценные данные.

Comment: snapshot это состояние диска, а текущее состояние это файл изменений к последнему snapshot, то есть откат это стирание инкремента, если восстановите его может быть отмените откат

Comment: @PavelGridin, т.е удалился какой-то файл, и я могу попробовать его восстановить?

Comment: да, то есть теперешний файл текущего состояния, надо заменить на старый, хотя может имя поменялось, тогда надо в конфигурации изменить, я уже давно перешел на vmware и не помню всё в точности. Текущий диск (vdi по моему) после отката должен быть маленьким и постоянно расти во время работы